# Javascript Selectbox Select All Feature

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried to add select all function on my buttons but there is a problem with jquery.min files.

I have these on my header.php page;

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

and I'm using these code for select all function;

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
function toggle(source) {
  checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('foo');
  for(var i=0, n=checkboxes.length;i<n;i++) {
    checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
  }
}
</script>
```

When I remove javascript includes on header.php and add these includes on anket.php, select all boxes thing is working but other things are not (We use jquery for a few things). I need to make both work.

here is my html;

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-check">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th><input type="checkbox" onClick="toggle(this)" class="styled"></th>
                                <th align="center">Soru</th>
                                <th align="center">Durum</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td><input type="checkbox" name="foo" class="styled" /></td>
                                <td align="center">Aylık kazancınız nedir?</td>
                                <td align="center">Aktif</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><input type="checkbox" name="foo" class="styled" /></td>
                               <td align="center">Cinsiyetiniz nedir?</td>
                               <td align="center">Pasif</td>
                            </tr>


                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

Thank you.

Comment: HTML Please. weird you are loading jQuery but not using them.

Comment: Your code works http://jsfiddle.net/q88AH/

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

**html**

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-check">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <input type="checkbox" class="styled" id="allChk" />
      </th>
      <th align="center">Soru</th>
      <th align="center">Durum</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="foo" class="styled" />
      </td>
      <td align="center">Aylık kazancınız nedir?</td>
      <td align="center">Aktif</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="foo" class="styled" />
      </td>
      <td align="center">Cinsiyetiniz nedir?</td>
      <td align="center">Pasif</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**script**

```
$(function(){
    $("#allChk").on('change', function(){
        $("input[name=foo]:checkbox").prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
    });

    $("input[name=foo]:checkbox").on('change', function(){
        $("#allChk").prop('checked', 0 === $("input[name=foo]:not(:checked)").length);
    });
})
```